# images not showing on vscod Browser Preview

Tags: html, express, vscode-extensions

would appreciate some help here, my img html tag has the correct file path. However, when I launch the express server and try to view the image on vscod Browser Preview, I cannot see it (example picture in the link below). What could be the problem?

```
 <div class="dashboard"><!--Dashboard START-->
    <section class="navigation"><!--Navigation START-->
        <img src="imgs/iHome.png" alt="">
    </section><!--Navigation END-->
```

[This is a picture of the html file along with the directories on the left and the html img tag in the middle, and the Browser Preview with the missing image on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzeCC.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The App needs a **src** folder that has a sub folder **assets**. your Frontend js should be hosted in the src folder.
put your image in the src -> assets -> images/pic01.jpeg

then call it like this:

```
        <img src="assets/images/pic01.png" alt="">
```